# How do I get the props in this ES6 Class?

Tags: react-native, react-props, es6-class

I tried using constructor (props) but still getting cant find variable: props
Hot do I get the props in this:

```
    export default class DetailScreen extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: '399',
    checked: 'Pan Crust',
  };

  render() {
    const productId = props.navigation.getParam('productId');
    constselectedProduct = useSelector((state) =>
      this.state.products.vegProducts.find((prod) => prod.id === productId),
    );

    const {checked} = this.state;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

props are accessed with `this` in class components.

So, the first line in the render function should be

```
const productId = this.props.navigation.getParam('productId');
```

**Update**
For react navigation 5.x

You should be able to access route params like this

```
const productId = this.props.route.params.productId;
```

Hooks should be used in functional components. You should refactor your code to look like this instead

```
export const DetailScreen = ({route)} => {
const [value, setValue] = useState('399');
const [checked, setChecked] = useState('Pan Crust');
const productId = route.params.productId;

return (
   // return view here
 )
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but now I am getting error --- TypeError : props.navigation.getParam is not a function. (In 'this.props.navigation.getParam('productId'), 'this.props.navigation.getParam is undefined )

whereas I am passing the props like this in the parent

onPress={() =>
                  props.navigation.navigate('Details', {
                    productId: itemData.item.id,
                  })

Comment: I have updated the answer to use the recent react navigation to resolve your error. The second approach should solve your problem

Comment: Thanks for helping, but now I am getting error -- Invariant Violation: Invalid hook call. :(

Comment: You might want to refactor your class component to a functional component if you want to use hooks.

Comment: I think I might need to rewrite the details page

Comment: Yes. You need to refactor details page to a functional component if you want to use hooks